# ProgressBar in FrameLayout is way too big

Tags: android, layout, progress-bar, android-framelayout

I'm trying to implement a `ProgressBar` in my activity but the progress bar is huge (cf screenshot).
[image]
Editing the width or height properties in my layout doesn't change a thing.

Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/main_progressBar"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Do you have any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/main_progressBar" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: that's the secret of RelativeLayout ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you intentionally add the closing tag for the FrameLayout?

I think you wanted to have this layout.

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <ProgressBar
          android:id="@+id/main_progressBar"       
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <ListView
          android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
          android:layout_width="240dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
          android:background="#111"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
     </FrameLayout
```

Comment: According to the docs, FrameLayout should not contain anything else:
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
Edit: didn't see but my code was not full. I fixed my post.

Comment: I am using FrameLayout to have to Layout inside it mostly overlapping so that I can easily show/hide group of controls. The common usage is not to put anything so that you can use it to as a container but it can be used that way as well.